# SEH & x64 call convention, compiler bugs? or unwinding bugs?

Tags: windows, exception, visual-c++

My Code is like:

```
int bar()
{
    int st = XXX_OK;
    __try {
        ...     //exception occurs here
    }
    __except (filter()) //filter returns EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER and doesn't change rbp
    { 
        // `rbp` is changed when run here
        st = XXX_EXCEPTION;
    }

    return st;
}

int foo()
{
    int x = 0;  //Here rbp approximately equals rsp.
    int y = bar(); // bar changes the value of rbp.
    x = 1       // mov [rbp+0x10], 1; To access a stack-var. Since rbp is changed, crash here
}
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019#callercallee-saved-registers. rbp is nonvolitile and `bar` won't change it's value.

More, rbp is not always changed by SEH: suppose my code inside __try calls a function like this:

```
static int my_glcp_run(PLUGIN_CONTROL_BLOCK *pcb, void *data)
{

    string s;
    s += "-----\n";
    pcb->chkcode = 1024;
    const char *msgx = get_arg_as_string(data, 0);
    MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, msgx, "(Warning From xxx)", MB_OK);
    __readcr0();     //this line is to raise an exception
    s += "-----\n";  //**try to remove this line**
    sendmessage(s.c_str(), s.length());
    return 0;
}
```

if I remove `s += "-----\n"` then rbp is not changed otherwise rbp is changed. Indeed this line will never be executed but it changes the behavior of SEH unwinding. I wonder why.

My Question is: why does `bar` break the convention that he not change `rbp`?

Btw, my Dev is VS2013.

Comment: VS2013 was not a very lucky version.  Clearly you also have VS2019 so tell us what it does.

Comment: um, I tried vs2017, and the issue is gone. I think it a bug of vs2013